# How can I replace main() with WinMain()?

Tags: glut, win32gui

This is a fully functional Win32 console application. It compiles and runs. I found this program along with GLUT library.

But, I am not being able to replace main() with WinMain(), coz, they have different number and types of arguments.

How can I replace `main()` with `WinMain()` in the following program?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f (0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
      glVertex3f (0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   glFlush ();
}

void init (void) 
{       
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);    
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (250, 250); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("hello");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();    

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You should be using: `int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil) ` instead of int main() in all Win32 programs.

Comment: @EvanCarslake, and how does your comment help me?

Comment: @BROY He answered your question exactly.

Comment: Why would you want to replace portable `main` with unportable `WinMain`?

Comment: @n0rd, just for experimentation. Yes, you have a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `main` with `WinMain` like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    glutInit(&__argc, __argv);
    // rest of code previously in main
}
```

Note that you must link with the VC++ library for this to work.

Source: https://codingmisadventures.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/retrieving-command-line-parameters-from-winmain-in-win32/

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a WinMain that just calls your existing main function.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    main(__argc, __argv);
}
```